# show content over the opacity in css

Tags: css

I have applied `opacity` in my wrapper class and I want to show the loading image on my page.
The loading image is placed inside the wrapper with `opacity` adjusted. Due to this, the loading image is not showing clearly.
I want to show the loading image clearly, without opacity. Would someone please let me know how I could do it?

```css
 #wrapper{
     opacity:0.21;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
 }
 #loading{ 
     background-image:url('loading.gif');
     width:200px;  
     height:20px;
     z-index:10px;
     position:fixed;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
 }
```

Comment: Would you please add your html code too?

Comment: I can only think of the two ways of doing it that were already answered. Just keep in mind that the two different div's solution will work on every browser and that the RGBA's solution wont, because of the RGBA compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

If your background is a solid color, use an `rgba` `background-color` instead of `opacity`:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21); /* white, 0.21 opacity */
```

The results of the above will be that only the background of your element will be 21% opaque, not the element's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Everything within #wrapper will inherit the opacity you assigned, not matter its position. This is probably what you're doing:

```
<!-- #loading will have the same opacity of its parent element -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="loading"></div>
</div>
```

You must put the tags of the #loading element out of the #wrapper element.

```
<!-- #loading and #wrapper will have their own separate opacity -->
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```